# How to set dependency DLL paths in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, build, environment-variables

I am working with [Cyclone](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds) DDS, and they have two builds,
c build (contains multiple files in the bin folder)

[image]

and c++ build (contains DLL file in the bin)

[image]

after Cyclones DDS installation, I have to set these bin paths in system environment variables.

how can I avoid this? I need to set them in the visual studio 2017 itself. without setting paths in the system environment

or can I copy bin files into my project directory? so that I can use the project file on any PC which has visual studio 2017 without reinstalling CycloneDDS?

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: set the path environment variable in your project's launch settings?

Comment: @Alan Birtles where are launch settings located?

Comment: project properties, debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows by default will prefer `.DLL` files in the same directory as the `.EXE`. So while developing, you can put them in your Visual Studio Debug and Release folders. For other people, you include the DLL's in the installer.

The exception is the `*140.dll` stuff, for which you need the Visual C++ redistributable. That's installed as part of Visual Studio 2017, but can also be distributed independently (hence the name).